# How does ASP.Net handle session managment?

Tags: .net, asp.net, session

How will ASP.NET handle **session management**?

Comment: you can understand he's in an interview...

Comment: lol. maybe can direct the interviewer to SO.

Comment: Why do you want to cheat? Lack of knowledge is not shameful.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on MSDN article [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
and [ASP.NET Session Management Internals](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/ASPNETSessionInternals.aspx)